# Struts2 based quiz application using DB for getting questions and storing results

Tags: struts2

jsp file

```
 <s:iterator value="questions" status="status">
   <table border="3px" bgcolor="yellow">
   <tr bgcolor="white" >
   <td nowrap><s:property value="QuestionNumber"/></td>
   <td nowrap><s:property value="Question"/></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td nowrap><input type="radio" name="<s:property value="QuestionNumber"/>" value="1"/><s:property value="Option1"/></td>
   <td nowrap><input type="radio" name="<s:property value="QuestionNumber"/>" value="2"/><s:property value="Option2"/></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td nowrap><input type="radio" name="<s:property value="QuestionNumber"/>" value="3"/><s:property value="Option3"/></td>
   <td nowrap><input type="radio" name="<s:property value="QuestionNumber"/>" value="4"/><s:property value="Option4"/></td>
   </tr>
   </table>
   <s:hidden> </s:hidden>
 </s:iterator>
 <s:hidden id="answers" value="answers"/>
 <s:submit name="submit" onclick="submitform()"/>
</s:form>
```

property values are being populated from DB using the Action class.
My problem is that i want to collect the list answers for a quiz and get it to the java classes for evaluation of score. Im not able to get any idea as how to do it

My DB has Questions table with the list of questions with options and correct answer.

I have a Question Bean Object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an Action with a `private List<Question> questions;`, with Getter and Setter.

You populate your JSP reading the list from the Getter.

You can post that list back from the JSP to the Action's Setter by using OGNL for keeping informations on lines detail.

To do this, use Struts tags (`<s:radio` instead of `<radio` ) and set a name including the index of the line.

For example, with a textfield, instead of

```
 <s:iterator value="questions" status="status">
     <s:textfield name="question" />
 </s:iterator>
```

use something like (untested, maybe some adjustments needed)

```
 <s:iterator value="questions" status="status">
     <s:textfield name="questions[%{#status.index}].question" />
 </s:iterator>
```

Just adapt this for your radio case,

and in the Action you will receive your List fully populated.

(You can even validate a list posted like this usign Visitor validator: not your case, but it's worth knowing).

Comment: Thank you....that will work but "questions[#status.index].question" is not working how do i get to a particular item in the list in struts? say i want to access the 1st item in the list and access the attributes of that question item.

Comment: Can't remember the exact syntax right now, try <s:textfield name="questions[%{#status.index}].question" /> ...

Comment: nope not working...if u could help..this is the one thing thats creating the problem..i am not able to save the user answer. There is a attribute user answer in my question bean. i want to put the input value into that uservalue attribute i.e name="questions[%{#status.index}].UserAnswer"

Comment: I can confirm my latter syntax is correct. In your code, instead of `questions[%{#status.index}].UserAnswer` use `questions[%{#status.index}].userAnswer` . I'm assuming all the rest is fine (the page, the setter etc...)

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways  to do this. the easiest way is to implement `ParameterAware`, checkout the link [ParameterAware](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.6/docs/how-can-we-access-request-parameters-passed-into-an-action.html), then you can get all your parameters like this: (I'm assuming, `QuestionNumber` is a parameter of your bean `question`)

```
String param1 = parameters.get(question.getQuestionNumber);
```

you can put this line in a loop, so you can get all your parameters...